# Why value of both (x-- +x) and (x-- -x) are same in Java?

Tags: java, post-increment

Assume `int x = 1;`

`System.out.println(x++ + x);` ---> Output:3

`System.out.println(x++ - x);` ---> Output:-1

`System.out.println(x-- + x);` ---> Output:1

`System.out.println(x-- - x);` ---> Output:1

```
x = x++; 
System.out.println(x);  ---> Output:1
```

Can anyone please explain how post-increment works?
Note: All print statements are executed independently.

Comment: x-- returns 1 and then decrements to 0, then you add or subtract 0.

Comment: the pre and post (de)increment functionality dates back to an era where programmers used these operations to directly increment/decrement registers in the processor. When I'm thinking in a conscious way, I try to avoid these and use plain arithematic instructions which are easier to read. But when I'm up against a deadline or just trying to get something finished, I do still use them... I know, I'm bad :(

Answer (score 1):

When `x` is `1`, `x++` increments `x` to `2`, *but* the expression returns the value *before* the increment (or decrement): `1`.

`x++ + x` is equivalent to: `1 + 2`.

`x++ - x` is equivalent to `1 - 2`.

`x-- + x` is equivalent to `1 + 0`.

`x-- - x` is equivalent to `1 - 0`.

`x = x++` is equivalent to `x = 1`.